# Expand/collapse rows on WPF DataGrid

Tags: .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am looking for DataGrid in WPF where user should be able to expand/collapse the rows as given in below image. Grid should also support all CRUD operations like add/remove/update/delete rows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to spend a few $$ then the telerik [TreeListView](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/treelistview.aspx) does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

A hierarchical DataGrid doesn't come with WPF out of the box. There are several non-free controls out there (by [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/treelistview.aspx), [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Grid/), [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/products/wpf/data-grid/), [Xceed](http://www.xceed.com/Grid_WPF_Intro.html), etc.)

If you're looking for a free control, you might want to [have a look here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/davids/archive/2010/04/17/hierarchical-grid-with-wpf.aspx).